# Higher order spectral analysis in python

Tags: python, signal-processing

Are there higher-order spectral analysis software which can be used from python?

By `higher-order spectral analysis` I mean:

1. [(Cross) Bispectral analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bispectrum)
2. [(Cross) Bicoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicoherence)

etc.

The intended use would be to analyze, say, Cosmic Microwave Background radiation or EEG data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity,

The MATLAB [Higher Order Spectral Analysis](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3013-hosa-higher-order-spectral-analysis-toolbox) toolbox seemed to fit the bill, but it is no longer maintained.

I ported the code I needed to python [here](https://github.com/synergetics/hopcs)